# Find the elementary divisors and invariant factors

Tags: abstract-algebra

Hello I have problems with this exercise

Find the elementary divisors and invariant factors of each of the following groups

a) $G_1= Z_6 \times Z_{12} \times Z_{18}$,
b) $G_2= Z_{10} \times Z_{20} \times Z_{30} \times Z_{40}$.

a) I think that elementary divisors are $\{2,3,2^2,3,2,3^2 \} $ because is the prime decomposition of ${6,12,18}$.

b)  elementary divisors are $\{5 ,2 ,2^2, 5, 2, 3, 5, 2^3, 5 \}$

Thanks

Comment: Use the Chinese remainder theorem to split each factor into cyclic $p$-groups, then regroup.

Comment: 3 has to be twice.

Comment: How do I apply Chinese remainder theorem ?

Comment: Do you know this fact: if $a,b$ are coprime then $\mathbb{Z}_{ab}=\mathbb{Z}_a\times \mathbb{Z}_b$?